# Python's CSV module behaves differently in Django view

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a csv file with this test content:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Parsing this in the usual manner with the csv module works fine:

```
>>> for row in csv.reader(open('test.csv')):
...     print row
... 
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['7', '8', '9']
```

I then try and use the same process in a django view:

```
def upload_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductCSVUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for row in csv.reader(request.FILES['csv_file'].read()):
                print row
    else:
        form = ProductCSVUploadForm()
    return render_to_response('upload_csv.html', locals())
```

This gives the output:

```
['1']
['', '']
['2']
['', '']
['3']
[]
['4']
['', '']
['5']
['', '']
['6']
[]
['7']
['', '']
['8']
['', '']
['9']
[]
```

Is Django changing the data? How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Hehe, happened to me some times: I wrote a question, and when I was proof-reading it, the answer came to me. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt added to the top of the question:

> Just after posting, the answer came to me: removing the .read(). Feel free to remove this moderators if you wish.

The reason for the problem is `read` returns a string, which gives characters when iterated over, while `open` produces a file object, which produces lines when iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

I think you make a mistake by reading the file instead of just supplying it to the reader.

```
 for row in csv.reader(request.FILES['csv_file'].read()):
```

should be:

```
 for row in csv.reader(request.FILES['csv_file']):
```